# Mio more has stopped working

Tags: windows-7

When I try to open MioMore desktop 7.50 I keep getting the following message:-  MIO MORE HAS STOPPED WORKING. A problem has caused the programme to stop working correctly.  Windows will close the programme and notify you if a solution is available.  I have tried to open Mio More on 2 different computers (Vista & windows 7) and the same thing happens.  Also I have uninstalled it and reinstalled it but to no avail.  This is from a CD that came with a new satnav which I am trying to register for new map updates.  Please can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you contacted whoever makes MioMore? If this is happening on two different computers then this is a problem on their end. If you have a license or a user name with them, perhaps it is a problem with your account. Alternatively, if it needs to access the internet, there may be a problem with their servers.

Whatever the case may be, if you have the same problem on two different computers then it is a problem that does not depend on you but on them. Get in touch with them and sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

On your desktop icon MioMore right click and select properties Compatibility and check the Box: Run this program in compatibility mode for: Scroll down and select the operating system which applies to your system.